# Login failed in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect the user to another page when he is logged. I try this solution but the actual page is loading and not redirecting to other page.

The Address Bar conatin a new # at the end.

This is my code in Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc)
    {
        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            return View("~/Views/Client/Edit.cshtml");
        }
        else {
            return View("~/Views/Client/Create.cshtml");
        }
        return View();


    }
```

and this what I have wrote in View :

```
<div class="login" id="login">

    <div class="main-w3l">
        <div class="w3layouts-main" style="background-image:url('/template/web/images/bg3.jpg'); margin-top:50px;">
            <h2>Login Now</h2>


            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            }


            <form action="#" method="post">
                <input value="E-MAIL" name="Email" type="email" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-Mail';}" />
                <input value="PASSWORD" name="Password" type="password" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" />
                <span><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</span>
                <h6><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></h6>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="login" name="login">
            </form>
            <p>Don't Have an Account ?<a href="#" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", "Client") + "'") ;">Register Now</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my db.cs :

```
 public int Admin_Login(string Email, string Password)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ConnectionString)) { 
        int res = 0;
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_Login", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        SqlParameter oblogin = new SqlParameter();
        oblogin.ParameterName = "@Isvalid";
        oblogin.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
        oblogin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        com.Parameters.Add(oblogin);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        res = Convert.ToInt32(oblogin.Value);
        return res;
        }
    }
```

the problem persist when I ve tried to test using Javascfript like this :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc)
    {
        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = " Login Successful !";

        }
        else {
            TempData["msg"] = " Email or Password is wrong !";

        }
        return View();}


 @{
    if (TempData["msg"] != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('@TempData["msg"]');
        </script>
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `res`? What exact behavior do you want when user is authenticated successfully? What is the significance of `res` variable here?

Comment: It just a function to test if my code right or no, ( I used before alert function of javascript then I remplace it with this redirection), Email and password must both equals to the values that I have in my base, I will update my code to clear what I mean by res

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a View(); try doing this

```
return RedirectToAction("Client","Edit",new { Id= id});
```

This assumes that you have a Client controller with a Edit action that requires an Id parameter which you most likely do.

Comment: the problem is not in the controller I think, I tried also to test the function using javascript and the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Use this for redirection

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit","Client");
```

You need to changes your view

```
<div class="login" id="login">

<div class="main-w3l">
    <div class="w3layouts-main" style="background-image:url('/template/web/images/bg3.jpg'); margin-top:50px;">
        <h2>Login Now</h2>


        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)




            <input value="E-MAIL" name="Email" type="email" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-Mail';}" />
            <input value="PASSWORD" name="Password" type="password" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" />
            <span><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</span>
            <h6><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></h6>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="login" name="login">
}
        <p>Don't Have an Account ?<a href="#" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", "Client") + "'") ;">Register Now</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is not in the controller I think, I tried also to test the function using javascript and the problem persist

Comment: Do you have the "Client" controller? and that controller contains the "Edit" Action method? If yes then what is the parameter for Edit action method and Return type?

Comment: thanks @Ravi but I didnt yet create the Controller of Client, and I don't think that will make change beause as i mention in my Update, the problem persist without using edit and create.
PS : The code works when the code of Login is in another seperated view (not the Index view)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc)
{
    int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
    if (res == 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
    else 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View();
}
```

Take a look at this tutorial, it covers a lot of the basic stuff you will need to develop this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Comment: the problem is not in the controller I think, I tried also to test the function using javascript and the problem persist